# List all Shifts Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm using Graph API SDK in a C# Console Application and I'd like to list all the shift data from Microsoft Teams. But I'm unable to retrieve such information. Here is what I have done so far.

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) to list all shift, you have to provide the team ID in order to retrieve the shift, however, in my case, I have to retrieve all the shift from all the teams. So, I have to retrieve the list of the team first. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams#get-team-information-for-a-group) says that to retrieve all team you have to retrieve the list of groups first. I've followed the same approach and the following is the code that I've used.

```
var groups = await graphClient
  .Groups.Request()
  .Filter("resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')")
  .GetAsync();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.DisplayName);
    var shifts = await graphClient
       .Teams[group.Id]
       .Schedule
       .Shifts
       .Request()
       .GetAsync();  
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the Group list, however, I'm not able to retrieve the Shift list. When it tries to retrieve the Shift list the following error occurs:

```
Code: NotFound
Message: {
  "error":{
    "code":"NotFound",
    "message":"Sorry, the team was not found, or you may not have access to it.",
    "details":[],
    "innererror":{"code":"TeamNotFound"}
  }
}

Inner error:
    AdditionalData:
      request-id: c5ab5f5c-ec3d-463b-9b1f-0798734e94ce
      date: 11/11/2019 7:50:42 AM
      ClientRequestId: c5ab5f5c-ec3d-463b-9b1f-0798734e94ce
```

Would appreciate any help that can help me to list all the shift list from Microsoft Teams. Thank you.

Comment: In the Permissions section you have a list of required permissions to be able to retrieve shifts

Delegated (work or school account)  Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All
Your account has this permissions?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I do have Group.ReadAll and Group.ReadWrite.All permission active. still facing with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This error most likely occurs since `schedule` object is not provisioned. The point is [`List shifts` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-list-shifts?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) expects [`schedule` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/schedule?view=graph-rest-beta)  to be *provisioned*. From [`Get schedule` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/schedule-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http):

> During schedule provisioning, clients can use the GET method to get
>   the schedule and look at the `provisionStatus` property for the current
>   state of the provisioning. If the provisioning failed, clients can get
>   additional information from the provisionStatusCode property.

In `msgraph-sdk-dotnet` whether schedule provisioned could be determined like this:

```
var schedule = await graphClient.Teams[group.Id].Schedule.Request().GetAsync();
if (schedule.ProvisionStatus == OperationStatus.Completed)
{  
    //...
}
```

Here is an *updated* example (*which demonstrates how to retrieve shifts for provisioned schedule*):

```
var groups = await graphClient.Groups.Request()
            .Filter("resourceProvisioningOptions/Any(x:x eq 'Team')")
            .GetAsync();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
     var schedule = await graphClient.Teams[group.Id].Schedule.Request().GetAsync();
     if (schedule.ProvisionStatus == OperationStatus.Completed)
     {
          var shifts = await graphClient.Teams[group.Id].Schedule.Shifts.Request().GetAsync();
         //...
     }         
}
```